# I can't correctly tag the checkbox inside my custom adapter

Tags: android

I've been fighting with the adapter for three days (it's the first time I've faced this, I'm sorry if the code may seem like spaghetti) and although I have managed to get that when pressing the delete button I delete the item from the listview to which it corresponds, the checkboxes when I press one it acts on the other, I can't see why, since I make the tag in the same way as with the imageview.
Thank you very much in advance.

this is my code for custom adapter:

```
public class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Modelo> implements 
View.OnClickListener,CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {

private List<Modelo> mList;
private Context mContext;
private int resourceLayout;
private int lastPosition = -1;
private ViewHolder holder;


//CONSTRUCTOR
public ListAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource, List<Modelo> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
    this.mList = objects;
    this.mContext = context;
    this.resourceLayout = resource;
}




@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {


    holder = new ViewHolder();
    final View result;
    Modelo modelo = getItem(position);


    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(resourceLayout, null);
        holder.imagen =  convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        holder.check =  convertView.findViewById(R.id.textEdad);
        holder.textoNombre =  convertView.findViewById(R.id.textNombre);

        result = convertView;

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        result = convertView;
    }
    
    holder.imagen.setImageResource(modelo.getImage());

    lastPosition = position;
    holder.imagen.setOnClickListener(this);
   
    holder.check.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    holder.check.setTag(Integer.valueOf(position)); 

    holder.imagen.setTag(position);


    

    holder.textoNombre.setTextSize(20);
    holder.textoNombre.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
    holder.textoNombre.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    
    holder.textoNombre.setText(modelo.getNombre());

    return convertView;

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    int position = (Integer) v.getTag();
    Object object = getItem(position);
    Modelo dataModel = (Modelo) object;

    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.imageView2:
            super.remove(dataModel);
            Snackbar.make(v, "soy una imagen", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("No action", null).show();
            break;
        case R.id.textNombre:
            Snackbar.make(v, "soy un nombre", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("No action", null).show();
            break;

    }
}

@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton v, boolean isChecked) {
    v.performClick();

        if (isChecked) {

            holder.textoNombre.setPaintFlags(holder.textoNombre.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);

        } else {
            holder.textoNombre.setPaintFlags(0);

    }

}

private static class ViewHolder {
    TextView textoNombre;
    CheckBox check;

    ImageView imagen;
        public CheckBox getCheck(){
            return check;
        }
}
```

}

this my Modelo class:

```
public class Modelo {
private String nombre;
private CheckBox edad;
private int image;

//constructor vacio para poder inicializar modelos sin elementos
public Modelo(){

}

public Modelo(String nombre, CheckBox edad, int image) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.edad = edad;
    this.image = image;
}

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public CheckBox getEdad() {
    return edad;
}

public void setEdad(CheckBox edad) {
    this.edad = edad;
}

public int getImage() {
    return image;
}

public void setImage(int image) {
    this.image = image;
}
```

}

and this is my xml layout for item_row:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textNombre"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:foregroundGravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/textEdad"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:foregroundGravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical" />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:foregroundGravity="center"
        tools:srcCompat="@drawable/trash" />
</LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and main activity class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{
private ListView myListView;
private List<Modelo> mLista = new ArrayList<>();
private ListAdapter mAdapter;
private Button btn;
private EditText edt;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    myListView = findViewById(R.id.listview);
    btn=findViewById(R.id.button);
    edt=findViewById(R.id.edtTxt);

    btn.setOnClickListener(this);



    //inicializo el adaptador
    mAdapter = new ListAdapter(this, R.layout.item_row, mLista);

    //seteo el adaptador
    myListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);




}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(edt.getText().toString().equals("")){
        Snackbar.make(v, "No debe introducir campos vacíos", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .setAction("No action", null).show();
    }
    else
    agregaLista(edt.getText().toString(),new CheckBox(this),R.drawable.trash);
}
private void agregaLista(String producto, CheckBox check, int image){
    Modelo modelo = new Modelo();
    modelo.setEdad(new CheckBox(this));
    modelo.setNombre(producto);
    modelo.setImage(R.drawable.trash);
    mLista.add(modelo);
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

}

Comment: Hi , are facing unexpected  behavior like when you check it works fine and then when you scroll down and scroll up check goes away or checked on some other positions ?

Comment: no, when I give the image, it correctly removes the item that I want to delete, the problem is that when I for example create 5 items in the list, when I activate the first checkbox that should refer to item 1 it activates the item 5 and so on, touch the checkbox that touch activates the last item. This does not happen to me with the images, if I play from the same hypothetical list, item 3 removes item 3. I imagine that I am failing to use the tags, but I have run out of ideas. Thanks for responding.

Comment: ok I am looking into code , I will revert soon !

Answer (score 0):

ok, I think I just realized ... the holder is still static and that is why it only acted on that object, I had to assign that object to the class that acts as a bridge, Model. Perhaps it is not the best or most elegant way ... but it works for me ... however I accept any suggestion. Many thanks!